# What am i doing wrong here?(Anguar Routing)

Tags: html, angular

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2wX5.png)
Hey guys, so i am trying to learn Angular by building a simple application that should show the list of categories and create a new category but i am facing a problem, when i click on a link the search bar doesn't change it stays on the home page..
This is the app.component.html:

```
  <ul class = "navbar-nav">
      <li class = "nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/categories" class="nav-link" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page" >Liste des catégories</a>
      </li>
      <li class = "nav-item">
          <a routerLink="/create-categories"  class="nav-link" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page" >Ajout catégorie</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class = "container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and this is the app-routing-module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CategoriesDetailsComponent } from './intefaces/categories-details/categories-details.component';
import { CategoriesListComponent } from './intefaces/categories-list/categories-list.component';
import { CreateCategoriesComponent } from './intefaces/create-categories/create-categories.component';
import { UpdateCategoriesComponent } from './intefaces/update-categories/update-categories.component';

const routes: Routes =  [
  {path: 'categories', component: CategoriesListComponent},
  {path: 'create-categories', component: CreateCategoriesComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'categories', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'update-categories/:id', component: UpdateCategoriesComponent},
  {path: 'categories-details/:id', component: CategoriesDetailsComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Your code works fine, check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-isydry?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Maybe there is an error that halts execution in some other component of file. Are there any errors or warnings in the console?

Comment: No everything is fine there's nothing in the console

Comment: have you imported the AppRoutingModule in AppModule (or whatever your base module is named)?

Comment: Yes i did everything but i don't know where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 <a routerLink="/categories" class="nav-link" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page" >Liste des catégories</a>

const routes: Routes =  [
  {path: 'categories', component: CategoriesListComponent},
  {path: 'create-categories', component: CreateCategoriesComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'categories', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'update-categories/:id', component: UpdateCategoriesComponent},
  {path: 'categories-details/:id', component: CategoriesDetailsComponent}
];
```

for this

```
 <a routerLink="categories" class="nav-link" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page" >Liste des catégories</a>

const routes: Routes =  [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'categories', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'categories', component: CategoriesListComponent},
  {path: 'create-categories', component: CreateCategoriesComponent},
  {path: 'update-categories/:id', component: UpdateCategoriesComponent},
  {path: 'categories-details/:id', component: CategoriesDetailsComponent}
];
```

Comment: I actually forgot to import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts thank you guys!

Comment: Just a quick tip: when generating pages use the following command: `ng g module register --module account --route register`. This gives your a single module per page where you only load the modules you actually need to show that page. Then you can also add `PreloadAllModules` (see google)